# R: upload images to imgur

Tags: r, image-uploading, imgur

I have a folder with some images (in .png and .jpg). My goal is to upload them all to [imgur.com](http://imgur.com/) and get back the links or ids from each one.

I tried to install both packages `imguR` and `imgur_upload` but failled to install them.

Is there any quick workouround?

Comment: You could try the Imgur API https://apidocs.imgur.com/#4b8da0b3-3e73-13f0-d60b-2ff715e8394f in combination with the httr package https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/httr/vignettes/quickstart.html

Comment: What exactly are the error messages you are getting when you try to install them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with knitr. This will upload an image and return your URL:

```
setwd("yourWD")
install.packages(knitr)
install.packages("RCurl")
install.packages("XML")
knitr::imgur_upload("fish2.jpg", key = "Yourimguraccountkey")
```

Comment: I'm trying to use the imgur_upload function but I get `Error: Bad Request` not sure why... it worked once. Also, how can I get my own key?

Comment: You can get your own key by creating an account on imgur. You are probably getting the bad request because you dont have a key! It will upload an image and associate it to your imgur account.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you are logged in your imgur account in your default browser, log out. In R, try

```
tkn <- imgur_login()
```

Your browser will try to open:

```
https://api.imgur.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=1babd0decbb90f2&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A1410%2F&state=yVKVeDejjB
```

and give the error:

```
{"data":{"error":"redirect_uri_mismatch","request":"\/oauth2\/authorize","method":"GET"},"success":false,"status":400}
```

Delete the end of the url, leaving:

```
https://api.imgur.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=1babd0decbb90f2
```

Now you will have the screen to log in with your username and password, then you will get:

> Authentication complete. Please close this page and return to R.

```
#upload images
listoffileIDs <- character()
mylistf <- list.files(pattern = ".jpg|.png")

lapply(seq_along(mylistf), function(i)
{
  y <- upload_image(mylistf[[i]], token = tkn)
  Sys.sleep(5)
  listoffileIDs[[i]] <<- paste(unlist(account_images(token = tkn))[[1]])
  y
})
data.frame(mylistf = mylistf, listoffileIDs = listoffileIDs)

#add images to new album
firstalbum <-  create_album(listoffileIDs, title = "firstalbum",
               privacy = "hidden" , token = tkn)
firstalbum$id # album id

# add images to extant album https://imgur.com/a/ALBUMID
# example: get ID of first album
firstalbum <- account_albums(token = tkn)[[1]]#
add_album_images(firstalbum, listoffileIDs, token = tkn)
```